# No option set display to 1920x1080 in the settings

Tags: display

I have elementary os 6 installed on my laptop and when I open the display section in the settings to change it to `1920x1080` the option is not there

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot of Elementary OS 6]

Hello Abdallah,

Please visit Display option in Hardware Category in System Settings. There you will see a "Gear" symbol in top right, on opening which you can see options related to Resolution and Screen Rotation.

Thanks,
Animish Yadav

Comment: I know but the size I want is not there